# Spring Boot - ignore application.yml / bootstrap.yml inside .jar file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a spring cloud application using config server for fetching configuration. We are using Spring Boot `1.5.4` & Spring Cloud `Dalston.SR2`.

For deployment purposes we are providing external `bootstrap.yml` file and specifying its location with `spring.cloud.bootstrap.location` parameter.

We already had some struggle with the fact that, for couple of properties, service fell back to .jar's `bootstrap.yml` / `application.yml`

The only way I could find to solve that, was changing name of external configuration files with `spring.config.name` and `spring.cloud.bootstrap.name`. Then, the original names from .jar won't be matched and taken under consideration.

Is there are other way to tackle that?

Comment: What repository type are you using? Git, native? Anymore configuration you can give? Version?

Comment: Versions of Spring Boot and Cloud added. Actually we are using MongoDB backend - private fork of https://github.com/spring-cloud-incubator/spring-cloud-config-server-mongodb which work with latest Cloud version. However, I added Cloud usage information only because `bootstrap.yml` file behaves in same fashion as `application.yml`. Even without Spring Cloud "problem" exists. I know that the behaviour follows the specs (order of property sources for ext. configuration - _15. Application properties packaged inside your jar_), but it gave us some headache in the past.

Comment: bootstrap.yml is a spring cloud feature, so a boot app without spring cloud will never see it, but should see application.yml in a jar.

Comment: Correct, without Cloud I'm referring only to `application.yml`. Not sure if my intention is clear enough - let me try to paraphrase: For Spring Boot application (w/o Cloud) I want to specify external `application.yml` and disallow Spring Boot to resolve yaml from jar file (so it won't be available as a property source in service application environment). If Cloud is in place I want to do the same for `bootstrap.yml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve that by upgrading to Spring Boot 2.x because they fixed the behavior of `spring.config.location` (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#configuration-location) which also affects `spring.cloud.bootstrap.location` in the same way

See also that question [Different behavior of spring.cloud.bootstrap.location since Spring Boot 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54204333/different-behavior-of-spring-cloud-bootstrap-location-since-spring-boot-2)

Comment: You are correct. That's what we did :) Thank you for answering this - I totally forgot!