# Different behavior of spring.cloud.bootstrap.location since Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I noticed a different behavior of the property `spring.cloud.bootstrap.location` since Spring Boot 2.x

**Behavior in Spring Boot 1.x:**

- Build in bootstrap.properties file inside the JAR *is* regarded
- Specified bootstrap.properties file is regarded

**Behavior in Spring Boot 2.x:**

- Build in bootstrap.properties file inside the JAR *is not* regarded
- Specified bootstrap.properties file is regarded

Reason is that since Spring Boot 2 the behavior of the `spring.config.location configuration` has been fixed and the property `spring.cloud.bootstrap.location` works now also as desired.

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#configuration-location

I restored the origin behavior by adding the default search locations to the property in addition `spring.cloud.bootstrap.location=classpath:/,classpath:/config/,file:./,file:./config/,file:/my/special/search/location`

Should there be introduced also a new property `spring.cloud.bootstrap.additional-location` like the `spring.config.additional-location`?

Hint: This is how the BootstrapApplicationListener currently works:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/57c2f9a154f3d4146135529261f071a00ab47ea9/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/BootstrapApplicationListener.java#L145-L156

Comment: Sure, file an issue in spring-cloud-commons?

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/466